# How to finish Fetch data completely and assign it to component state before proceeding further in componentDidMount React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have to perform multiple fetch queries. Based on my first query i have make to make a multiple other queries after receiving all the i should be able to assign the data to the react component state. It appears that i am assigning the values to the component state before the fetch method is finished and hence they appear empty array.

I have tried by removing the inner fetch method outside and performing the query.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Sensors from './iot/Sensors';

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
      super (props);
      this.state = {
        status: 'disconnected',
        devices: [],
        dataPoints: []
      };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Get Zigbee devices
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/ssapi/zb/dev')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {

      this.setState({
        devices : data
       })
      data.map((device) => {
        const dataPoint = []
        JSON.parse(device.metadata).dataGroups.map((datagroup) =>{
          const url = 'http://localhost:3000/ssapi/zb/dev/' + device.id + '/ldev/' +  datagroup.ldevKey + '/data/' + datagroup.dpKey;
          fetch(url)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) =>{
            dataPoint.concat(data)
            console.log('Data', data);
            console.log('Inside dataPoint', dataPoint);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }) // dataGroups.map
        console.log("Final dataPoint", dataPoint);
        const dataPoints = this.state.dataPoints.concat(dataPoint);
        this.setState({ dataPoints });
      }) // data.map

    }) // fetch
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Render Devices', this.state.devices);
    console.log('Render dataPoints', this.state.dataPoints);
  }][1]][1]
```

I am expecting a final component states that look like this
or in render function - console logging should look like this.

```
devices = [{},{},{},{},{}...]
dataPoints = [[{},{},{},..], [{},{},{},..], [{},{},{},..], ....]
```

Answer (score 0):

A common React pattern would be to set a loading flag in your state and display a loader (or return null) as long as the page is not loaded.

Constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      status: 'disconnected',
      devices: [],
      dataPoints: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }
}
```

In your componentDidMount: (simplified)

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/ssapi/zb/dev')
  .then((res) =>
    this.setState({data: res.json(), loading: false});
  )
}
```

In your render function

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <div>Loading ... Please Wait.</div>;
  }

  // Here render when data is available
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

In your componentDidMount function you are doing 2 setState. You should only do one to prevent unecessary rerenders.

In your example, remove the first

```
  this.setState({
     devices : data
  })
```

And combine both at the end instead `this.setState({ dataPoints, devices: data });`

Answer (score 0):

I thing the reason is in `dataPoint.concat(data)`, array.concat returns a new array, it is an immutable function. To solve the proble just try: `dataPoint = dataPoint.concat(data)`

Answer (score 0):

your code `const dataPoints = this.state.dataPoints.concat(dataPoint)` inside map will always concat empty array, because fetch is asynchronus and your `dataPoint` will only get value after api calls.

Other issue is `dataPoint.concat(data)` concat returns a new array but you are not storing the new array you can use `dataPoint = dataPoint.concat(data)` or `dataPoint = [...dataPoint, ...data]`

You need to wait for the result of api calls before `const dataPoints = this.state.dataPoints.concat(dataPoint)`. You can use Promise.all

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Sensors from './iot/Sensors';

class App extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
        status: 'disconnected',
        devices: [],
        dataPoints: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    // Get Zigbee devices
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/ssapi/zb/dev')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
            devices : data
        })
        //Using forEach instead of map because we don't need the return of map
        data.forEach((device) => {
            const urls = JSON.parse(device.metadata).dataGroups.map((datagroup) =>
                'http://localhost:3000/ssapi/zb/dev/' + device.id + '/ldev/' +  datagroup.ldevKey + '/data/' + datagroup.dpKey) // dataGroups.map
            Promise.all(urls.map(fetch))
            .then(responses => 
                Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json()))
            )
            .then((data) =>{
                //This data will be array of responses of all fetch fired
                //destructuring response in array
                const dataPoint = data.reduce((acc, curr)=> acc.concat(curr),[]) 
                const dataPoints = this.state.dataPoints.concat(dataPoint)              
                console.log('All Data', data);
                console.log('Inside dataPoint', dataPoint);
                this.setState({ dataPoints });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }) // data.map
    }) // fetch
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

render() {
    console.log('Render Devices', this.state.devices);
    console.log('Render dataPoints', this.state.dataPoints);
}
```